# Change content of a custom template for different pages - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html, templates

I'm not too familiar with Wordpress, however I've been asked to use it for a website I'm building as the client would like the ability to add pages later on for certain events that may need to be created.

I'm aware that I can create a custom template, and then assign a Page to use that template, my question is, once this is done, what are the different ways that I can allow certain content areas to be changed by the client when creating a new page that uses the template.

For example, If i have a very bare custom template such as the following:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Retreat Template
*/

get_header(); 

?>

<div class="container-fluid retreat-page-container">
   <h1>The Event Title</h1>
   <p>Some Event Description</p>
   <a href="#">Some Event Link</a>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What are the tools I can use so the client is able to change the inner HTML of the `<h1>`, and `<p>` tags, or change the href and inner HTML of the `<a>` tag, when creating a new page that uses the template. Or even things like changing the background image for the container. Obviously, custom CSS could be used to change things like the background image etc, but what if it were wanted to be a different background image for each event that uses the same template?

The default page I created, index.php, uses widgetized areas which work great for adding text areas etc. within the wp-admin. However, even If I were to add widgetized areas to the custom template, the content that is put in each widgetized area would then be the same across each page that uses the template.

Can anyone please give a Wordpress rookie some advice?

Comment: When you add a page the content that the user changes is called by the action `the_content()`. Like you have the `get_foooter()` and `get_header()` functions. The content however is stored in the wp-mysql-db.

Comment: the_title() returns the page title

Comment: But where does the client enter the content @mcv

Comment: Admin panel -> edit page?

Comment: I presume that you're setting up your own theme, so you have to log into the admin panel SITE_URL/wp-admin and select pages, add a page or edit an already existing page. In your theme PHP the_content() will call the textarea that you will populate with the page details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best two tools that I can think of are:

1. redux (with the metaboxes add on) https://reduxframework.com/extension/metaboxes/
2. Advanced Custom Fields https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Redux has a cost while Advanced custom fields is free.    They both allow you store specific metadata about each individual page that you can then access through your php in the page template.   I use Redux on my main site I work with everywhere. https://trulaw.com

Redux is a little more advanced in terms of maintenance.   Its basically managed via config file in text format.    ACF is managed through plugin menus in wordpress.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. I'll take a closer look and mark the answer accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: After looking into it, I decided to use Advanced Custom Fields. The options you provided were exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.